# JQUERY On Screen Keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I search touch screen keyboard, I found this link.

### JQUERY On Screen Keyboard

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/jquery-screen-keyboard-plugin/

I like this plugin so much.
But as my client requirement is a little more complex, I need to modify this plugin.
What I want to modify is keyboard position. Now current keyboard position is

```
left:0 top:0
```

but I want to change Applie Ipad Keyboard style layout.(eg. keyboard position is round about 
    left:0 top:50%)

So, If you know how to do It, please share with me.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The keyboard appears on the `input` not at the top left corner.

Comment: Sorry to make you difficult to understand @avall. Let's say, we try to search something at google.com from Applet Ipad. When we put mouse cursor at google search text box, at that time Apple Ipad keyboard automatically appear at the bottom of the screen. I want to copy this Keyboard style to Touch Screen Monitor which is not Applet Ipad. Any way, thank for your co-operation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I started using the on screen keyboard.
It turned out that I needed to update to the latest version of JQuery-UI and that solved my positioning problem